# Exit WIth Toast is not working when I initialize both functions on one button (To Exit Application and Show Toast)

Tags: java, android

Exit With Toast is not working when I initialize both functions on one button (To Exit Application and Show Toast).

And Toast is appearing but `finish()` or `MainActivity.finish()` or `System.exit (0)` is not working at all, and if used without Toast then it works well.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button exit =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast t  =Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),getString(R.string.exitMessage),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();

                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "Is Not Working" means.

Comment: what does finish() do here? and what do you want to do? if you want to see the toast you wont be able to because finish probably stops the activity.

Answer (score 0):

If your *activity's* class name is *MainActivity* for example

```
t=Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.exitMessage),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Replace `getApplicationContext()` with your `ActivityName.this`
Now your Toast should appear.

Comment: Yes ... toast is appearing but finish() and MainActivity.finish () and System.exit (0) is not working at all... and if used without toast then it works

Comment: Try adding `return;` statement after `finish()`